# Need help in solving a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find solution of PDE  $$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\left ( y-\sqrt{1-z^2} \right )\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=0$$
I can solve this equation, when (x) but not (z) under the square root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lagrange method works well to reduce a PDE of first order to ODE by the help of equations: $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y-\sqrt{1-z^2}}$ and $dz=0$. Once we see that $z=c_1$, a constant. We can put $z=c_1$ in the second term we have a separable ODE
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y-\sqrt{1-c_1^2}}.$$ whose solution is $$y-\sqrt{1-c_1^2}=c_2x.$$ Since $c_1=z$, we have $y-\sqrt{1-z^2}=c_2x$. Thus the solution takes the form: $z=f\bigg(\frac{y-\sqrt{1-z^2}}{x}\bigg)$, where $f$ is an arbitrary continuously differentiable function. Instead of this we could use the method of characteristics.